# Avoiding threads restarting when changing activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Right now, when I change the activity, my thread seams to go to sleep or something. And when I come back to the main activity, there are two threads running, doing the same things. I'm not sure if this is the case, but it seems like it's something equal.

```
...
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static double cowCount = 195;
public static double income = 0.100;
static boolean twiceCow = false, Threadrunning = false;
...
public void inc() {
    new Thread(new income()).start();
}

class income implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20;) {
            final int value = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    cowCount = cowCount + income;
                    refresh();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my thread looks like.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    handler = new Handler();
    checkThread();
}

private void checkThread() {
    if (Threadrunning == false)
    inc();
    Threadrunning = true;
}
public void inc() {
    new Thread(new income()).start();
}
...
public void refresh () {
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
myTextView.setText("You Have " + String.valueOf((nf.format(cowCount)) + " Cows!"));
}
```

I don't really understand what I've done wrong.

Comment: Aren't you setting `Threadrunning = false` somewhere on the code?

Comment: Yes, in the beginning of the main class.

Comment: But on declaration or on the onCreate or something? From your code I cannot see what's been doing wrong either. You could put a log on `inc()` and see when it's called.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I made an edit, I hope it made things clearer.

Comment: You need to show enough code so we can tell what's going on.  The code you have shown never calls checkThread()

Comment: When you say "change the Activity" do you mean start a new activity?

Comment: Edited once more, changing "inc();" to "checkThread();". Yes, change the Activity is starting a new activity. It seems to work now that I changed "inc();" to "checkThread();". However, now it seems like the refresh() method isn't being run each time thread is being run.

Answer (score 1):

Please review this post: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Consider your activity re-start as the same thing as a config change.

This pattern, i.e. using a retained Fragment as a container for your thread, and proxying UI updates via callbacks to your activity, is a pattern that will work much better for you.

In your case you'd need only a single TaskCallback for your UI refresh(), e.g. onRefreshCowCount(int cows);

Comment: I'm reading up on it. It seems promising, but I just have a question I think you can answer: Am I supposed to create fragments in the main class or in a separate class?

Comment: Do it just like the post, instantiate the fragment in your main activity.  The main difference is that "DummyTask" will be your thread, not an AsyncTask.  The thread will be a private inner class of the Fragment.  The fragment "knows" about the activity via onAttach/onDetach.